# Javascript - outputting set string value from dropdown/select box with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three select dropdowns, each with a few options which have unique values. I want these values to be outputted comma separately, as shown in the jsfiddle. i've put them into an array, is there an easier/better way of doing this? also can it be outputted into a textfield? and finally I can't figure out how you can clear the array with another button.

Heres the jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/m6nRU/4/

```
  var content="<b>Text Message:</b><br>";
   for(var i = 0; i < serial.length; i++) {
     content +=serial[i]+",";
  }
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++) {
    var value = selects[i].options[selects[i].selectedIndex].value;
    arr.push(value);
}

console.log(arr); //array of selected values
```

Edit: Just saw the jQuery tag:

```
var values = $("select").map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have no idea how to apply that to my code! any chance you can edit the jsfiddle?